# Lambda Expression Search

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, lambda

I want to perform the equivalent of a 'dynamic SQL' search for a product with variable search criteria, but in C# code. For example, a product is defined like this:

```
class Product
{
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My search control has a textbox for price and a textbox for quantity. If the user specifies something, it should be included in the search (otherwise not). In reality, my product has many more than 2 properties.

How can I build a lambda expression generically based on any such search by variable criteria?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two possible ways to achieve this: 1) Building expressions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx); 2) Using the overloaded Where method in EntityFramework which have string as parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx). I can't say exactly which way is better for you, it depends on complexity of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than building a lambda expression, build up the query bit by bit:

```
IQueryable<Product> productQuery = db.Products;

if (userHasSpecifiedPrice)
{
    productQuery = productQuery.Where(p => p.Price == userSpecifiedPrice)
}
// etc
```

Note that this won't *execute* the query until you start to use the results.

Query composition is one of the key strengths of LINQ. (Expression tree composition - which is what you'd need to do if you wanted a single `Where` call - is rather harder, unfortunately.)

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow-up: is this technique still preferred if I need to 'join' across other db objects (i.e. Warehouse the product is in)?

Comment: @John: It becomes trickier if you need to *conditionally* join. If your join is unconditional, then it should be fine.